# Imagefield replacement

Tags: media

I have a content type with a multivalue imagefield, each image contains the image file and title attributes.

A lot of the images need to be uploaded again so I need them to replace. If I remove and add the image again I need to add the title again which I do not want because of the number of images.

Is there a module or solution to replace it instead of remove and add it?

Comment: Have you applied any style(resize, scale etc) to these images?

Comment: For some yes and for some no. I installed imageflush already for clearing if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "For some yes and for some no" ? You said in your question that you have one field. So applying an image style should implement on all images. Is it clear?

Comment: Some images of some nodes I use in a view. Then I apply the image style. The same images (in the same field) of some nodes I use in another view in which I do not apply a image style.